# Getting redirected to /login instead of /secrets after successful Google authentication in Node.js app

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, google-oauth, google-auth-library

I'm working on a Node.js application that uses Google authentication via OAuth2. After successfully authenticating with Google, the user is redirected to /login instead of the expected /secrets page. However, I noticed that if I click on the address bar and hit enter without making any changes, it then redirects me to /secrets as expected.

Here's an overview of my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const argon2 = require('argon2');
const crypto = require('node:crypto');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const mongoSanitize = require("express-mongo-sanitize");
const csrf = require("csurf");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');

const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(mongoSanitize());
app.use(
    helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
        directives: {
            defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
            scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
            styleSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
        },
    })
);

const csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true });
const rateLimiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 60 * 1000,
    max: 5,
});

app.use(csrfProtection);

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/secretoxDB",{
    family: 4,
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: String,
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

const authenticateToken = (req, res, next) => { // 1

    const token = req.cookies.jwtToken;
    if (!token){
        res.redirect("/login");
    }

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.redirect("/login");
        }

        req.user = user;
        next();
    });
};

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    return res.render("home");
});

app.route("/register")
.get(function(req, res) {
    const token = req.cookies.jwtToken; // req.headers['authorization'];
    if (token) {
        try {
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
            return res.redirect("/secrets"); 
        } catch (err) {
            return res.render("register", { err: null, csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
        }
    }
    return res.render("register", { err: null, csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
})
.post([
        body("email").isEmail().normalizeEmail(),
        body("password").isLength({ min: 8 }),
    ],
    csrfProtection,
    rateLimiter,
    async function(req, res) {
        // ...
        // There are no redirects to login here
    }
);

app.route("/login")
.get(async function(req, res) {
    const token = req.cookies.jwtToken; // req.headers['authorization'];
    if (token) {
        try {
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
            return res.redirect("/secrets"); 
        } catch (err) {
            return res.render("login", { err: null, csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
        }
    }
    return res.render("login", { err: null, csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
})
.post([
        body("email").isEmail().withMessage("Invalid email").normalizeEmail(),
        body("password").notEmpty().withMessage("Password is required"),
    ],
    csrfProtection,
    rateLimiter,
    async function(req, res) {
            // ...
        }
    }
);

app.get('/auth/google', (req, res) => { // 2
    const client = new OAuth2Client(
        process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI,
    );
    const redirectUri = process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI;
  
    const authUrl = client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: ['email', 'profile', 'openid'],
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
    });
  
    res.redirect(authUrl);
});

app.get('/auth/google/callback', async (req, res) => {
    const client = new OAuth2Client(
        process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI,
    );
    const redirectUri = process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI;
  
    try {
        const code = req.query.code;
        const tokenResponse = await client.getToken({
            code,
            redirect_uri: redirectUri,
        });
        const gtoken = tokenResponse.tokens.id_token;

        const userInfo = await client.verifyIdToken({
            idToken: gtoken,
            audience: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        });

        const email = userInfo.getPayload().email;

        let user = await User.findOne({ email: email });

        if (!user) {
            user = new User({
                email: email,
            });
            await user.save();
        }

        const token = jwt.sign({ userID: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { algorithm: 'HS512' })
        res.cookie("jwtToken", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: Boolean(process.env.SECURE_COOKIE),
            sameSite: "strict",
        });

        return res.redirect('/secrets');
    } 
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.redirect('/register');
    }
});

app.get("/secrets", authenticateToken, function(req, res) { // 3
    return res.render("secrets");
});

app.get("/logout", function(req, res) {
    res.clearCookie("jwtToken");
    return res.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

I did a console.log inside `if(!token)` of `authenticateToken()` and it turns out at the moment when the function is called there's no cookie named "jwtToken" saved in browser, but it gets created moments after hence causing this problem.

Here's the problem I'm having:

[image]